# How to setup a CICD build with 2 Artifactory instances

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, artifactory, cicd

I have 2 Artifactory URLs, one for production and another for non-production. I want to configure CICD pipeline that publishes non-production artifacts to 1 Artifactory server and final prod artifacts to the other Artifactory URL.

Can we have 2 Artifactory repo entries in the same pom.xml file? How can the above scenario be achieved in a single CI job?